# Conversion of an image grabbed with MIL-lite to use it with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have been searching a solution on the internet for almost 2 days but what I found doesn't seem to work on my computer.

What I'm using :

- Matrox Vio DUO
- OpenCV 2.4.5
- MIL-lite
- Ubuntu 10.04

I have already tried the cvcap_mil.cpp file that you can find [here](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/src/highgui/cvcap_mil.cpp?rev=1714).

This code isn't working for my project too :

```
   IplImage* rgb_frame;
   rgb_frame = cvCreateImage(cvSize(w,h), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3 );
   MilImage = MbufAllocColor(MilSystem, 3, w, h,8+M_UNSIGNED,M_IMAGE + M_GRAB,M_NULL);
   MbufGetColor(MilImage, M_BGR24+M_PACKED, M_ALL_BAND, (void*)(rgb_frame->imageData));
   rgb_frame->origin = IPL_ORIGIN_BL;
   cvFlip(rgb_frame,rgb_frame,0);
```

Do you have any idea how to do it ?

PS : My Matrox Vio card is working fine.

EDIT : I found a way to grab black and white images. Here is the solution for those interested :

```
MIL_ID MilApplication, /* Application identifier */
MilSystem, /* System identifier */
MilDigitizer, /* Digitizer identifier */
MilImageRGB, /* RGB Buffer */
MilImage1Child, /* R child */
MilImage2Child, /* G child */
MilImage3Child; /* B child */

//init
MappAlloc(M_DEFAULT,&MilApplication);
MsysAlloc(M_SYSTEM_VIO,M_DEFAULT,M_DEFAULT,&MilSystem);

MdigAlloc(MilSystem,M_DEFAULT,MIL_TEXT("M_DEFAULT"),M_DEFAULT,&MilDigitizer);

/*get width & height of cam*/
long width = MdigInquire(MilDigitizer,M_SIZE_X,M_NULL);
long height = MdigInquire(MilDigitizer,M_SIZE_Y,M_NULL);
MbufAllocColor(MilSystem,3,width,height,8+M_UNSIGNED,M_IMAGE+M_GRAB+M_PROC+M_DISP,&MilImageRGB); /*Erster Buffer*/

/*first Child (r channel)*/

MbufChildColor2d(MilImageRGB,M_RED, 0, 0, width , height ,&MilImage1Child);
MbufChildColor2d(MilImageRGB,M_GREEN, 0, 0, width , height ,&MilImage2Child); /*second Child (g channel)*/
MbufChildColor2d(MilImageRGB,M_BLUE, 0, 0, width , height ,&MilImage3Child); /*third Child (b channel)*/
IplImage *pIplImgProcessed = cvCreateImage ( cvSize ( width,height ), 8,1 );

/* get one image */
MdigGrab(MilDigitizer, MilImageRGB);


/*copy first child to buffer*/
MbufGet ( MilImage1Child, pIplImgProcessed->imageData );



// Visualise in a Qt label
Mat src(pIplImgProcessed);
QImage qImage = Mat2QImage(src);
QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(qImage);
ui->label_2->clear();
ui->label_2->setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(ui->label_2->size()));


//release
MdigFree(MilDigitizer);
MbufFree(MilImage1Child);
MbufFree(MilImage2Child);
MbufFree(MilImage3Child);
MbufFree(MilImageRGB);
MsysFree(MilSystem);
MappFree(MilApplication);
```

Thank you for your help.
Thibaut.

Comment: Could you specify what "doesn't work" ? Does it crash, do you see part of the grabbed image ? Is your new buffer all black ?

Comment: I can grab images with the functions of MIL-Lite and show them in a Window.
If I use the code I linked to make the conversion, the image i'm getting is green with horizontal blue stripes (The new buffer is not black).

Comment: I've just had better results. Now I can see that i'm grabbing an image with shifted pixels. The bottom of the image is filled with green.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of things you should check.

1. Does cvCreateImage really expect a BGR24+Packed buffer ? Maybe it's BGR32+Packed or BGR24+Planar... I'm using EmguCV so I'm not used to this function in OpenCV.
2. Make sure the data you get with MbufGetColor() has the same pitch as your OpenCV buffer (align property).
3. The code you give in example doesn't even grab but I suppose you're doing it in your real code. Since your buffer seems half-filled (garbage+green) I think you may be grabbing only one field at a time (2 fields = 1 frame)
4. You should try to clear your buffer and set one white pixel at (0, 1) alternatively with OpenCV and MIL to see if they appear at the same place in your image.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I will try what you suggested me. 

I found a solution (I edited my question) to get a black and white image. In my final project I will need the colored one so i'm still searching.
I'll let you know if i make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You could create Red, Green, and Blue child buffers of an RGB image in MIL.  Then have OpenCV point to each of those buffers as if they were three separate gray images. Finally, in OpenCV you could merge those three channels into a single OpenCV color image.